# Make move animation permanent in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a simple application where there are 3 buttons. When user clicks any of the button, they are animated(moved) to their new positions! All this works from this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                  delay:0.1
                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
             animations:^
 {
 //Moving the Sum (UIButton which will move through this animation)
 CGRect frame =  Sum.frame;
 frame.origin.y = -20;
 frame.origin.x = (-120);
 Sum.frame = frame;
 .....
....
 }
             completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {
 NSLog(@"Completed");
//adding subview after the animation is complete! newView is an example!
[self.view addSubview:newView];}];
```

The Problem is that once i add a subview to the main view, All buttons come back to their old position! meaning they weren't moved permanently.. how can i solve this? Plz help guys!

Comment: can you explain what is the relation between `Sum` and `newView`? and what do you mean by: 'once i add a subview to the main view'? what is the main view? how and where you add which subview to it? more detail, please...

Comment: Main View is Self.view!, Sum is the button which being moved, newView is the subview i am trying to add after the move animation is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you add a view? A layout is performed. You could have done two mistakes

1. You are using autolayout.

   If you are using autolayout, changing frames directly is not advised and a relayout will update the views to their original position using current constraints.
2. You are setting the frame position in `layoutSubviews`, `viewWillLayout` or `viewDidLayout`.

   Check where you are setting the original position. Can the method be called multiple times?

Comment: Yes i am using autolayout.. i did turn it off! and buttons didnt come back to thier original position! Well this is the solution.!

I am setting the frame position in xib file at first than changing it when a button is clicked. Thank you Sulthan!

Comment: @Araibkarim When using autolayout, animations are a bit more complicated, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have save the X,Y Position of the new frame & then set this frame by coding.

Comment: When i tried that before adding the subview .. it ddnt work! but when i tried it after adding the subview..buttons back came to their original position and went back to the animated position. the result wasnt desirable! Is there any way to make the move animation permanent?

Comment: Sorry, but can post some more code for how you adding buttons to subview??

Comment: [self.view addSubview:newView]; i am using this .. newview is just an example..

I first move the button and when the move animation is complete i call  the code i mentioned above.! See the block.. You can see the code in the question

Comment: can you add the image of new view & view? I think self.view is a superview & that's why it might be taking the (0,0) in subview(new view).